# Cannot schedule a bash script with crontab

Tags: bash, php, cron

I am going crazy as not understanding what I am doing wrong.

I wrote this bash script to run a php script with nohup.
It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup /usr/bin/php /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/folder/script.php $argv > fileoutput.txt 2>&1 &
```

when I run in in terminal as ./script.sh it does work, I can see the process running if I grep php and also my database updates.

Now I am trying to automate this process with crontab with this instruction:

```
43 * * * * /bin/sh /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/folder/script.sh
```

I am just changing the minute currently to test the automation as I will add a cycle of $argv to be executed when I manage to get this to work.

I have applied chmod 777 to the script.sh and now I really have no idea what else to fix.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `$argv` and how is it set? it's unlikely that it will be in the `cron` execution environment. Do you see any errors in `fileoutput.txt`?

Comment: $argv is just a variable that you can write and updates the php script to then query the DB in my case. I see no errors as my problem is that the script doesn't even run.

Answer (score 0):

The desktop's runtime environment differs from the `cron` runtime environment. Read `man 5 crontab` and run

```
(echo "=== set ===";set;echo "===env ==="; env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias)
```

in both environments, and compare the results.